# Argv[] Not Registering Argument

Tags: c++, argv

Here's an excerpt of the code.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
string s;

if (argc == 2)
    argv[1] == s;             //I tried this with and without brackets

else if (argc == 1){
    cout << "Enter a number." << endl;
    cin >> s;
    }
else
    {    
    cout << "Use only one argument" << endl;
    }

cout << s << endl;
```

However, if there's an argument (first condition) then it's ALWAYS 0. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
argv[1] == s;
```

should be

```
s = argv[1];
```

Your current code compares `argv[1]` to an empty string using `==`, and discards the result of comparison. It looks like you are after getting the first argument into the string `s`, so you need an assignment.

Comment: Wow thanks so much, I'm not sure if this is a beginner mistake or I'm just stupid

Comment: @Foxic I think this is a case of compiler being too forgiving: it should have told you that your `==` operation has no effect, prompting you to fix the problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I know GCC usually gives a `warning: statement has no effect.` for that kind of thing. I'm not sure if that's only when using `-Wall` or something, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Well, it calls the function `std::operator==(const char*, const std::string&)`.  A compiler shouldn't know that function has no useful side effects.